# How does rails know which private params method to use to filter params from a form before providing to controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand that when a form is submitted:

- it's via a `POST` that routes to a controller action
- that parameters are filtered via a private method
- those filtered params then become available in the controller action

The question: can we define multiple `private` params methods (e.g. for multiple different forms), and (most importantly) if so, how does rails 'know' which `private` params method it should use to filter the params submitted?

#### Example

Suppose we `rails generate scaffold viewer`.

Then somehow the form in `new.html.erb` knows that the parameters need to be filtered using `viewer_params` *and* the controller somehow knows that it will be receiving params via `viewer_params`. I can't work out how the app knows to connect the form in `new.html.erb` with the `viewer_params` method for filtering? (suppose we had multiple private params methods defined, how does the app know which one to use?)

#### Why?

I made a form and want to tell the app which private filtering method `require(..).permit(...)` it should use

Comment: You mean like multiple `def blog_params` methods or something like that?  You question is a little confusing as to what it is solving exactly.  Can you add some code related to the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @RockwellRice say I generate a scaffold, but then add one extra view (with a form), one extra controller for that form to submit to, and an extra private params method to filter the params. (I initially had a code example but the question literally went 10 times as long - but I can put it back in if it helps?)

Comment: @RockwellRice added a very simple example, hopefully it makes sense?

Comment: Well you could just create another method for params and set that when creating the new object.  So there would another method called `viewer_params_2` and then you could just do `@view = Viewer.new(view_params_2)` in the other method.  What happened when you tried setting this up in your code an it (I guess) didn't work?

Comment: @RockwellRice I think the answer is "the app will use whatever private params method is called from the controller". Is that all there is to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already concluded the view is not concerned with whitelisting parameters at all. Handling user input is the job of the controller in MVC. Whitelisting parameters is done in response to a form submission when you bind the request parameters to model instances.

The view just takes data from the controller (in the form of model instances) and renders it.

How the Rails scaffolds handle parameter whitelisting is really just a pretty simple example of convention over configuration. You have [a code template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/921b55d300feed6524580cbdb307ef62300d4a16/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt) which generates the controller which looks like this:

```
class <%= controller_class_name %>Controller < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_<%= singular_table_name %>, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # ... 

  # POST <%= route_url %>
  def create
    @<%= singular_table_name %> = <%= orm_class.build(class_name, "#{singular_table_name}_params") %>

    if @<%= orm_instance.save %>
      redirect_to <%= redirect_resource_name %>, notice: <%= "'#{human_name} was successfully created.'" %>
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ...

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_<%= singular_table_name %>
      @<%= singular_table_name %> = <%= orm_class.find(class_name, "params[:id]") %>
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def <%= "#{singular_table_name}_params" %>
      <%- if attributes_names.empty? -%>
      params.fetch(:<%= singular_table_name %>, {})
      <%- else -%>
      params.require(:<%= singular_table_name %>).permit(<%= permitted_params %>)
      <%- end -%>
    end
end
```

There is nothing magical about the name`#{singular_table_name}_params` and there nothing stopping you from doing parameter whitelisting inline instead of in a separate method. Its just a simple convention engrained by the templates. You can easily use any number of methods that you want to whitelist the parameters:

```
class ViewersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @viewer = Viewer.new(create_params)
    # ...
  end

  def update
    @viewer = Viewer.new(update_params)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def base_parameters
     [:foo, :bar, :baz]
  end

  def create_params
    params.require(:viewer)
          .permit(*base_parameters.union([:a, :b]))
  end

  def update_params
        params.require(:viewer)
          .permit(*base_parameters.union([:c, :d]))
  end
end
```

However to supply the name of whitelisting method from the form you would need to pass a hidden input which leaves it open to user tampering. I would question if this is something you really need.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for explaining. Just on this: "Whitelisting parameters is done in response to a form submission when you bind the request parameters to model instances.". To be very precise, I think it's true that it doesn't matter what fields are in the model, so long as the *params method is happy, then those params it lets through will be available in the controller? (e.g. if it `permits` some param that isn't a field in the model, it will still be let through to the controller I think?)

Comment: Yes that's correct. The process of binding parameters in Rails is really just passing a hash of user input to a model instance. What parameter whitelisting does is slice that hash into a set of permitted parameters to avoid mass assignment vulnerabilities. The controller doesn't really know or care about the model's actual attributes.

Comment: The model on the other hand will raise a NoMethodError if you pass a key in the hash that does not correspond to a setter on the model (like the ones that ActiveRecord creates automatically based on your database schema).

Comment: I think I understand. So if the object passed to the form is `@physician` then it would only allow fields from `Physician` ? (irrespective of what's `permit`ted in the *params method?)

Comment: Parameters whitelisting is kind of irrelevant when you're talking about a form in the view. The form builder which is the block argument to `form_for`/`form_with` just wraps a model object and calls the getter methods on the object to fill in values for the inputs. It doesn't care at all how that data got there. And it won't restrict you from creating inputs for any attributes that where not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out through process of elimination.

> How does rails know which private params method to use to filter params from a form before providing to controller action?

The answer is: it doesn't filter params *before* providing to the controller action (in fact, it won't filter them at all unless told to do so).

`params` are filtered **only** when some code runs inside a controller action that tells the app to do so. For example, in

```rb
  def create
    @viewer = Viewer.new(viewer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @viewer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @viewer, notice: 'Viewer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @viewer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @viewer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

We see `@viewer = Viewer.new(viewer_params)`. In this, the `viewer_params` is filtering the params. I.e. it's running:

```rb
    def viewer_params
      params.require(:viewer).permit(:user_id)
    end
```

Until it runs `viewer_params`, the controller doesn't know anything about the permissibility (or lack thereof) of the supplied parameters.